Who is the woman who speaks when the Ravagers stop the Benatar?
This woman speaks when the Ravagers stopped the Benatar from entering
the bio-formed structure in space:

WOMAN: (ON SPEAKER): Hey, guys, you're about to be boarded by the United Ravagers. You can surrender and turn over any stuff worth anything and live...or you can die. Totes up to you.

Who exactly is this woman?

This is Mainframe

Mainframe is a disembodied robotic head with artificial intelligence
and speaks with a feminine voice [voiced by Miley Cyrus in GotG2, and Tara Strong in GotG3], despite programmed to be male. It
became a Ravager captain, and went on many heists with other Ravager
captains led by Stakar Ogord, until it dissolved.

James Gunn on Replacing Miley Cyrus as Mainframe in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3

